# iOS Mobile Safari Service Worker Cache Limit

Tags: javascript, ios, html, caching, capacity

What is the Service Worker cache limit for the iOS Mobile Safari browser?

I'm creating a web-app for iPad that contains several mp4 video files. The videos must be cached in order for it to operate offline, and I can't get a confirmed size on the max cache capacity.

Comment: Based on my readings, it seems that the cache limit for a browser service worker is based on the client hardware specs

Answer (score -5):

Safari and Safari mobile does not support service workers. See [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#feat=serviceworkers).

UPDATE: Support is now in. Original answer was dated 2016.

Comment: Service Workers are now supported as of macOS Safari 11.1 and iOS Safari 11.3.